# erorr when trying to reach view with findviewbyId

Tags: android, kotlin, view, findviewbyid

```
class main_fragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_fragment, container, false)

    val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)
    viewPager.adapter = PageAdapter(childFragmentManager)

    val tabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout)
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
}
```

}

i am getting an erorr Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type View?

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
    class main_fragment : Fragment() {
   val view: View
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_fragment, container, false)

    val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)
    viewPager.adapter = PageAdapter(childFragmentManager)

    val tabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout)
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
return view
}

}
```

Comment: this code gives me an erorr <html>Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getView()Landroid/view/View;):<br/>fun `&lt;get-view&gt;`(): View defined in com.example.exchanger.main_fragment<br/>fun getView(): View? defined in com.example.exchanger.main_fragment

Comment: change the name view to myView and it will work

Answer (score 0):

override  onViewCreated method

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
and then use view parameter from this function

Comment: how would this code be written in kotlin?

Comment: override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_fragment, container, false)
}





override public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){ val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)
    viewPager.adapter = PageAdapter(childFragmentManager)

    val tabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout)
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager) }